# Possibly not getting a response from HttpUrlConnection?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to POST cached data to a server when my App finishes.
If i get a positive response (200, `HTTP_OK`), i'll delete the cached data.

In the event of a different status code, or whatever exceptions may happen (`MalformedURLException`, `UnknownHostException`, `IOException` and even `Exception`) during the Request, i keep the cached data.

If the Application is resumed and the cached data is still there i'll try to send it again.

On rare occasions, i find duplicate data on the Server which suggests that the cached data was sent twice. I'm wondering how that's possible.

This is implemented using a `Thread(Runnable)`.
The Runnable sends the post using `HttpURLConnection` like this (simplified):

```
private void run() {
    try {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream();
        out.write(myCacheDataString);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        int httpStatusCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        conn.disconnect();

        if (httpStatusCode == 200) {
            // Okay! delete cache
        } else {
            // Not okay. Keep Cache
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // Not okay. Keep Cache
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // Not okay. Keep Cache
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // Not okay. Keep Cache
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Not okay. Keep Cache
    }
}
```

You'll have to trust me that my caching strategy is working, and that the Server is responding to my POSTs accordingly.

Is it in any way possible that my client is "missing" the 200 Response from the Server?

[EDIT]: minSdkVersion is 10

Comment: It is possible that you getting timeout on your app but on the server side the cache is already saved, had the same issue with my messaging app sending multiple messages because was getting timeout.

Comment: Also can it be possible that the server saves the data and does not return a 200 ? maybe 201 ? or any other code ?

Comment: @Kgabol so you think setting the timeout on the `HttpUrlConnection` (`setConnectTimeout(int)`) should do the Trick? Because the execution might be stuck somewhere?

Comment: @RobertEstivill It should not. The Server will only respond with 200 OK on saving the data. Error codes otherwise.

Comment: So the timeout / connection break after saving data (and on the way back to the client) is the real scenario. The only way to really fix it (after all there's no possible way to control it within the same request) is to send a client-side auto-generated id with the data and have the server check for it. If the server detects that already stored that data, then it ignores it, otherwise it saves it.

Comment: you are probably simply getting an exception, but since you are not even logging the exceptions, you can't know that.

Comment: @RobertEstivill thanks! That's how we are most likely going to handle it. Any idea on a scenario why the timeout is happening though? Force-quit application?

Comment: @njzk2 i am logging them, just not in the pseudocode

Comment: It can happen at any time and there's no way to avoid it. If the server has finished processing the request and the network connection drops on the way back to the client, 1) there's no way for the server to detect the connection drop if using http protocol, 2) no way for the client to know up until what point the server was able to process

Comment: @RobertEstivill alright, thanks a bunch!